# how to move a div on right (Like the input caret) as I type a letter?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

I am trying to create a custom input caret. I have achieved a little thing but that's not all.
I wanted custom blinking animation and I got it. But now I want my custom caret to move on right side as I type anything (like the real caret does).
BTW I'm using an `<i>` element to imitate the effect of real caret.
Below is my Working Code.

```css
.cursor {
   position: relative;
}
.cursor i {
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: 80%;
   background-color: gray;
   left: 5px;
   top: 10%;
   animation-name: blink;
   animation-duration: 800ms;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   opacity: 1;
}

.cursor input:focus {
   caret-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes blink {
   from { height: 0%;
          top: 50%;}
   to { height:80%;
        top:10%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
<input type="text" class="rq-form-element" />
<i></i>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest Javascript/Jquery for this?
**Thank You very much ! :)**

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to exclude some older browsers, this will do:

```
<div>
  <span class="rq-form-element" contentEditable></span>
  <i></i>
</div>
```

The span will become an editable field, as we're adding `contentEditable` attribute to it. You might have to use some additional CSS to style it properly, but it will automatically move the `<i></i>` as you type - as long as you don't set a width to `rq-form-element`.

Comment: Is it compatible with most of the browsers?

Comment: Greg can you edit the CSS according to your suggestion. Sadly I'm unable to do so !

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, I only showed you the concept of how to achieve it. I'm not going to do all the work for you,